# How to abstain from the voting process in a custom @PreAuthorize expression method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application with

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
private static class GlobalSecurityConfiguration extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {
}
```

and will override accessDecisionManager() to use the UnanimousBased decision manager.
I wish to protect methods using a combination of the jsr250 @RolesAllowed annotation, and a custom @PreAuthorize bean method for the case where a particular role needs further validation, something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myapi/{someId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@RolesAllowed({Roles.STAFF, Roles.EXTERNAL})
@PreAuthorize("@myBean.customMethod(authentication, #someId)")
public void myApiMethod(@PathVariable Long someId) {
    //code
}
```

with custom validation in a bean like so:

```
@Component
public class MyBean {
    public Boolean customMethod(Authentication authentication, Long resourceId) {
        //verify here that if user has the EXTERNAL role then they are allowed to see resourceId.
        //return true if they have access, false if they don't.
        //For any other role, we want to abstain from the vote. But how? this doesn't allow me to return a null.
    }
}
```

I was assuming that i could abstain from the vote by returning a null. However i get a NullPointerException on returning null. The @PreAuthorize appears
to require a boolean (not Boolean) response.

So, how do i abstain from the vote using @PreAuthorize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afaik, you can't.

as you already have override `accessDecisionManager()`, you can register your own implementation of a voter, instead of the default `PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter`. Your implementation can handle this null scenario and return `ACCESS_ABSTAIN`.

But why don't you just answer 'yes', and let others voters deny the access ?

Comment: I'm accepting your answer because the deeper i dig the more you appear to be correct: you can't.
But why have all these ways of doing security, and a voting mechanism across them, if the @PreAuthorize doesn't play properly with the voting system? it makes me feel like i am missing something and 'doing it wrong'.

Comment: just answering 'yes' seems dangerous. If someone accidentally forgets to add the RolesAllowed, and say role 'OTHER' tried it then PreAuthroize would allow them through. If PreAuthroize could abstain and RolesAllowed were forgotten then it would be access-denied because all voters abstained. These seems safer in the face of accidents.

Comment: Not only would i need to provide my own voter implementation, would need to provide my own ExpressionBasedPreInvocationAdvice and deep down the interface returns a boolean, so it all seems too hard. In fact it turned out that overriding accessDecisionManager required me to copy-paste private methods too keep the same behaviour. At that point i abandon this approach!